# How to install and implement font awesome icons in angular 12

Tags: angular

How to install and implement font-awesome icons in angular 12

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

For more details check this link will help You.

Comment: can you please let me know how I can import social icons (like Instagram youtube face) in components. I'm trying using documentation but have not succeeded thanks!

Comment: All available icons listed here. https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons?d=gallery&p=2

Comment: Don't forget Your vote 

Comment: I would love to do but I don't have sufficient reputation to cast a vote. Will do it later for sure.